# Why is there a _ga cookie on my intranet app when I don't use Google Analytics?

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, intranet

I noticed a recent error log e-mail showed that one of my intranet app's users had, for our non-FQDN, never-GA-using intranet app, a standard `_ga` cookie in addition to my app's normal cookie on the domain `myapp`.  How could it have gotten there?

(I.e. shouldn't that require me to include some Analytics script of some kind?  How can they put a cookie on my domain without me serving up any of their code?  Isn't this some kind of security breach, when I never use Google Analytics?)

The only thing I can think of that might be related is we had a few users who would be redirected to a Google search for "myapp" when they would write `myapp` in the address bar, after Firefox changed the default way this was handled around version 32 or so.  But how that would then allow GA to send a cookie for our private non-internet-accessible domain is what I don't understand, because I thought that was not allowed.

Comment: Perhaps one of your users did for a lark execute the GA code in his browsers console. Frankly I do not think this is an answerable question, but Google does not and cannot slip cookies into your domain and there would be no profit for them if they could.

Comment: @EikePierstorff, I don't think this particular user knows what the browser console is, let alone would go get GA code from somewhere and try to execute it.  Maybe it's a browser bug?

Comment: Assuming the user didn't do it, the only scenario in which I could see this happening would be if the user had a browser plugin installed that manipulated the page into making the call.

Comment: @joshb that could be it, I'll check their installed plugins.